# How to split string between different chars?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the float that sits between two different signs.

```
text="value_1 : 12.14% ,value_2 : 14.14% ,value_3 : 92.23% ,value_3 : 17.22% ,"
```

How can I grab only the number between the `:` and `%` chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very not pythonic way, also making many assumptions.

```
text = "value_1 : 12.14% ,value_2 : 14.14% ,value_3 : 92.23% ,value_3 : 17.22% ,"

s = text.split(',')
for part in s:
    if '%' in part:
        number = part.split(':')[1].strip()[:-1]
        print(number)
```

Here's the regex solution:

```
text = "value_1 : 12.14% ,value_2 : 14.14% ,value_3 : 92.23% ,value_3 : 17.22% ,"
regex = r'\:.*?(\d+\.\d+)%' # find all parts starting with the ';' char, 
                            # then skip all characters until digit is found, 
                            # and then extract the float number until the 
                            # '%' char appears
res = re.findall(regex, text)
for r in res:
    print(r)
```

Comment: thank you very much, but may I ask what you meant by not a pythonic method ?is there another or better way to get the result I need?

Comment: @BaßelMutlak I mean that the first solution is quick and dirty one, and very specific. I prefer the regex.